# Angularjs Form input text is always undefined

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs

Here is my form

```
<form>
<input class="text_box1" type="text" name="email" ng-model="forget.email" >
<button style="width:auto" class="sign_up" ng-click="doForget(forget)">Get a Password</button>
</form>
```

Inside my `app.js` I have

```
.when('/forget', {
                title: 'forget',
                templateUrl: 'resources/views/forget.php',
                controller: 'authCtrl'
            })
```

And inside the `authCtrl` controller i tried to do the console of the input value.

```
$scope.doForget = function (customer) {
        console.log($scope.email);
    };
```

But i am getting the console as `undefined` always.

How can i get this value ?

Comment: Typo. ng-model is `forget.email` and you are outputting `$scope.email`

Comment: What is the result of: `console.log(customer);`?

Comment: @PSL While i do `console.log(forget.email);` i am getting error `ReferenceError: forget is not defined`

Comment: @user5071852 that is because it is not defined. It will be a property on the scope. Also what is on the property that you are passing in as customer?

Comment: @Hackerman If i do `console.log(customer);` i am getting the `$scope.forget()` in the console

Comment: @PSL How can i define it, so that i wanted to get it in the console..

Comment: @user5071852 You do not have to define it, you just have to access it as `$scope.forget.email` but i believe `customer` itself will give you that object

Comment: Thanks i am getting it when i do `console.log($scope.forget.email);` But for your update when i do `console.log(customer);` i am getting `function $scope.forget()`

Answer (score 2):

No need to define `email` just

```
$scope.forget={};
```

And get a value in controller by

```
$scope.forget.email
```

Answer (score 1):

First define folowing in your controller

```
$scope.forget={
email:'',
}
```

After that you can get the value by

```
$scope.doForget = function (customer) {
        console.log($scope.forget.email);
    };
```